# ArgumentError: New columns must have the same length as old columns

Tags: julia, julia-jump, ijulia-notebook

I have a problem in the simulation loop. The problem is that new matrices don't have the same length as old variables.  I'm not sure if the problem comes from the initial values of the variables or from the simulation loop.

I'm using julia v1.0.3

```
using Distributions

using DataFrames

n=5000
t=15000
gamma   = 2;        
delta   = 0.057;   
betta   = 0.99;     
alfa    = 0.47;     
miz     = 1;         
roz     = 0.75;     
sigmaz  = 0.013;    
phi     = 0.05;     
rok     = 0.7;     
mie     = 1;        
roe     = 0.7;      
sigmae1 = 0.05;     
sigmae2 = 0.1;     
roez    = 0.3;      
lambda  = 0.8;      
tau     = 0;        
ass     = 31.7838916986589918973; 
kss     = lambda*ass;              

vtheta1 =0.1; 
vtheta2 =0.2;
vtheta3 =0.3; 
vtheta4 =0.4; 
vtheta5 =0.5; 

n_lambda = trunc(Int, lambda * n)

eshocks1= rand(Normal(0.0,sigmae1),n_lambda ,t); 
eshocks2= rand(Normal(0.0,sigmae2),n-n_lambda,t); 
zshocks1= rand(Normal(0.0, sigmaz),1 , t); 

# Variables:
a=ones(t,n);
c=ones(t,n); 
y= ones(t,n);
k=ones(t); 
w=ones(t); 
r=ones(t); 
z=ones(t);
l=ones(t);
e=ones(t,n);
```

## Initial values of the variables:

```
a[1:2,1:n_lambda].=ass;
a[1:t,(n_lambda+1):n].=0;
k[1:2].=lambda*ass;
c[1:n_lambda,1].=(ass^alfa)*(1-tau*alfa)-delta*ass;
```

## Loop of simulation

```
for i = 2:(t-1)
    k[i]=lambda*mean(a[i,1:n_lambda]);         
    z[i]=(1-roz)+roz*z[i-1]+zshocks1[i];
    l[i]=1+(1-lambda)*roez*(z[i]-1)/(1-roe);
    w[i]=(1-alfa)*z[i]*((k[i])^(alfa))*l[i]^(-alfa);
    r[i]=alfa*z[i]*((k[i])^(alfa-1))*l[i]^(1-alfa);
    for j=1:n_lambda
        e[i,j]=(1-roe)+roe*e[i-1,j]+eshocks1[j,i];
        a[i+1,j]=(vtheta1)+(vtheta2)*a[i,j]+(vtheta3)*e[i,j]+(vtheta4)*z[i]+(vtheta5)*k[i];
        y[i,j]=(1-tau)*r[i]*a[i,j]+w[i]*e[i,j]; 
    end 

    for m=1:(n-n_lambda)
        e[i,m+n_lambda]=(1-roe)+roe*e[i-1,m+n_lambda]+roez*(z[i]-1)+eshocks2[m,i];
        c[i,m+n_lambda]=w[i]*e[i,m+n_lambda]+tau*r[i]*k[i]/(1-lambda);
        y[i,m+n_lambda]=c[i,m+n_lambda];
    end
end
```

## Preparing the variables for the calculation of the Gini index

```
ysort = ones(t,n);
for i = 1:(t-1) 
    ysort[i,:]=sort(y[i,:]); 
end
```

## Calculation of the Gini index of income

```
giniY=ones(t);
for i=1:(t-1)
    sum1=0;
    sum2=0;
    for j=1:n
        sum1=(n+1-j)*ysort[i,j]+sum1;
        sum2=ysort[i,j]+sum2;
    end
    giniY[i]=(n+1-2*(sum1/sum2))/n;
end

tab = DataFrame()
tab[ :periodos] = 15000
tab[ :familias] = 5000
tab[ :giniY]= giniY

return tab
```

ArgumentError: New columns must have the same length as old columns

Stacktrace:
 [1] insert_single_column!(::DataFrame, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Symbol) at /home/jrun/.julia/packages/DataFrames/IKMvt/src/dataframe/dataframe.jl:366
 [2] setindex!(::DataFrame, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Symbol) at /home/jrun/.julia/packages/DataFrames/IKMvt/src/dataframe/dataframe.jl:420
 [3] top-level scope at In[1]:104

Comment: I would recommend you to try posting your questions in English, as then it is easier for StackOverflow users to answer them.

Answer (score 2):

This is the way to create `tab` `DataFrame` you want (assuming you want `periodos` and `familias` columns to contain constant values):

```
tab = DataFrame(periodos=15000, familias=5000, giniY=giniY)
```